# Exclude folders for s3cmd sync

Tags: amazon-s3, synchronization, s3cmd

I am using s3cmd and i would like to know how to exclude all folders within a bucket and just sync the bucket root.

for example

```
bucket
folder/two/
folder/two/file.jpg
get.jpg
```

with the sync i just want it to sync the get.jpg and ignore the folder and its contents.

```
s3cmd --config sync s3://s3bucket (only sync root) local/
```

If someone could help that would be amazing i have already tried the --exclude but not sure how to use it in this situation?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should indeed use the `--exclude` option. If you want to sync every file on the root but not the folders, you should try :

```
s3cmd --exclude="/*/*" sync local/ s3://s3bucket
```

Keep in mind that a folder doesn't really exist on S3. What seems to be a file `file` in a folder `folder` is just a file named `folder/file`! So you just have to exclude file with the pattern `/*/*`.

Comment: Hi sylvian thanks this works for me ;)  s3cmd --exclude="/*" sync  s3://s3bucket local/

Comment: I want to point out that to exclude a specific folder I had to use `--exclude="folder/*"` instead of `--exclude="/folder/*"`.

Answer (score 6):

As mentioned by @physiocoder excluding a folder is done the following way:

`s3cmd --exclude 'foldername/*'`

So that is different from the question but I landed on this page due to its title.