# How to download an S3 bucket's directory structure (without files)?

Tags: amazon-s3, s3cmd

I need to download the directory tree of a folder in a bucket recursively, with the caveat of not downloading any of the files themselves (they are large). This is what I have so far:

```
s3cmd --dry-run --recursive --no-delete-removed --verbose --rinclude='^[^.]*$' 
    --rexclude='[^.]*$' sync s3://bucket_name/folder/ ~/Downloads/local_folder/
```

which correctly skips the files, but it isn't downloading the folders.

Here are some related questions I found

- [Exclude folders for s3cmd sync](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21891045/exclude-folders-for-s3cmd-sync)

Comment: As noted in the answer to the other question you cited, there are no folders to download.  The folders in S3 are largely an illusion, a side effect of the `/` delimiters in the key names... s3cmd may not have a simple way of downloading things that don't actually exist.  A direct API call to the REST interface for ListObjects allows you to fetch "common prefixes" -- the "folders" -- but whether s3cmd leverages this in a useful way is unknown to me, fwiw.

Answer (score 3):

Amazon S3 does not have folders. The closest concept is a [`CommonPrefix`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ListingKeysHierarchy.html), which allows listing of files "within" a directory.

You would have to write your own program (eg in Python using `boto`) to retrieve these common prefixes and create a directory structure locally.

BTW, these days it is better to use the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) rather than `s3cmd` since it can work with *all* AWS services rather than just Amazon S3.