# Exclude sub-folder for Sync to AmazonS3 using s3cmd

Tags: amazon-s3, synchronization, s3cmd

I am using the following command with s3cmd to sync a wordpress wp-content folder to S3

```
/usr/bin/s3cmd sync -r --delete-removed --add-header "Cache-Control:max-age=31536000" /home/USERNAME/public_html/wp-content/ s3://www.mydomainBucketName.com/wp-content/
```

However I want to exclude a sub-folder from being synced as it is just not necessary to have on S3. The sub folder is:

```
/home/USERNAME/public_html/wp-content/uploads/backupbuddy_backups
```

I have looked at the thread at [Exclude folders for s3cmd sync](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21891045/exclude-folders-for-s3cmd-sync) however it gave me a starting idea, but it is not working.

This is the new s3cmd that I'm tried which is not working:

```
/usr/bin/s3cmd sync -r --exclude "home/USERNAME/public_html/wp-content/uploads/backupbuddy_backups/*" --delete-removed --add-header "Cache-Control:max-age=31536000" /home/USERNAME/public_html/wp-content/ s3://www.mydomainBucketName.com/wp-content/
```

I also tried adding a / in the exclude statement so it was: --exclude "/home but that did not work either.

I have reviewed the exclude docs at http://s3tools.org/s3cmd-sync but I am coming up blank. Appreciate some assistance :)

Comment: Side-note: These days, it is recommended to use the official [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) rather than `s3cmd`. It has a `aws s3 sync` command that [can include/exclude files](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/).

Comment: Thank you. I will look into that. I was following along with s3cmd because that is what I had used in the past.